# Add tab to profile.php wordpress plugin development

Tags: plugin-development, admin, hooks

I already know how to add an extra field in user profile. But in my case I have A lot of field to add and It is good practice that your form is not too long. So I decided to implement tab panel in the top level of the form so that form is shorter and easy to use by the user. Anyone has the snippiest for this will be appreciated.

HERE IS MY SAMPLE CODE

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', $plugin_admin, 'wp_user_social_tab' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', $plugin_admin, 'wp_user_social_tab' );
public function wp_user_social_tab( $user ) {
?>


<ul id="tabs">
    <li class="active">Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
    <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>

<?php 

}
```

What I want is to be like this

[image]

Comment: If I am correct then this [tabbed-navigation](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-5-tabbed-navigation-for-your-settings-page--wp-24971) is what you are looking for? I could have copy/paste the code but without explanation(*because that would enlighten some, and is too much imho*) it would be incomplete here on wpse. My advice is to take a good look, adjust to your needs and off you go.